# Storage occupied by a union doesn't match as expected

Tags: c++

This union contains uint32, uint16, and int8. Using sizeof() function I've found they occupied 4, 2, and 1 byte. So the union should contain 7 bytes. But it showing that it occupied only 4 bytes. I got no clue why...

```
int main(){
  union{
    uint16_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    int8_t c;
  }u1;
cout<<sizeof(u1)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to have a size of 7? A `union` occupies enough space for its largest member. Are you confusing a `union` with a `struct` or `class`?

Answer (score 6):

From [C17 document](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) 6.7.2.1, page number 82,(16)

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its
> members.

`uint32_t b` is the largest member, with 4 bytes size. Hence, the size of the union is 4 bytes.